# Java - Why is the background of this applet not showing up light blue (cyan)?

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet, setbackground

This code is from a Java textbook by Lewis Loftus. It shows the example output in the textbook and the background is light blue (cyan). I think there is something wrong with:

```
setBackground(Color.cyan);
```

Here is the whole program:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Snowman extends JApplet
{
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Draws a snowman.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public void paint(Graphics page)
    {
        final int MID = 150;
        final int TOP = 50;

        setBackground(Color.cyan);

        page.setColor(Color.blue);
        page.fillRect(0, 175, 300, 50);  // ground

        page.setColor(Color.yellow);
        page.fillOval(-40, -40, 80, 80);  // sun

        page.setColor(Color.white);
        page.fillOval(MID-20, TOP, 40, 40);      // head

        page.fillOval(MID-35, TOP+35, 70, 50);   // upper torso
        page.fillOval(MID-50, TOP+80, 100, 60);  // lower torso

        page.setColor(Color.black);
        page.fillOval(MID-10, TOP+10, 5, 5);   // left eye
        page.fillOval(MID+5, TOP+10, 5, 5);    // right eye

        page.drawArc(MID-10, TOP+20, 20, 10, 190, 160);   // smile

        page.drawLine(MID-25, TOP+60, MID-50, TOP+40);  // left arm
        page.drawLine(MID+25, TOP+60, MID+55, TOP+60);  // right arm

        page.drawLine(MID-20, TOP+5, MID+20, TOP+5);  // brim of hat
        page.fillRect(MID-15, TOP-20, 30, 25);        // top of hat

    }
}
```

Comment: You set the `background` color of the applet, but never let the applet paint itself.  You should NEVER change the state of any component from within any paint method, this will just cause more paint events to be triggered, putting you into a never ending spiral as your applet consumes more and more CPU cycles. Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: It's really just for my own practice with graphics. Drawing rectangles and ovals and stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Never try to draw in a top-level component. Instead, create a class that extends JPanel, override its `paintComponent` method, be sure to call the super's `paintComponent` within the override, and then add the JPanel to your JApplet's contentPane. Also, set the JPanel's background in its constructor, not in its paint or paintComponent method.

Also, in future questions, please try to indent your code a reasonable and consistent amount. Good code formatting makes the code much easier to read and more importantly, to *understand*.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SnowManPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.CYAN;
   private static final int MID = 150;
   private static final int TOP = 50;
   private static final int PREF_W = 300;
   private static final int PREF_H = 225;

   public SnowManPanel() {
      setBackground(BACKGROUND);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.blue);
      g.fillRect(0, 175, PREF_W, PREF_H - 175);  // ground

      g.setColor(Color.yellow);
      g.fillOval(-40, -40, 80, 80);  // sun

      g.setColor(Color.white);
      g.fillOval(MID-20, TOP, 40, 40);      // head

      g.fillOval(MID-35, TOP+35, 70, 50);   // upper torso
      g.fillOval(MID-50, TOP+80, 100, 60);  // lower torso

      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.fillOval(MID-10, TOP+10, 5, 5);   // left eye
      g.fillOval(MID+5, TOP+10, 5, 5);    // right eye

      g.drawArc(MID-10, TOP+20, 20, 10, 190, 160);   // smile

      g.drawLine(MID-25, TOP+60, MID-50, TOP+40);  // left arm
      g.drawLine(MID+25, TOP+60, MID+55, TOP+60);  // right arm

      g.drawLine(MID-20, TOP+5, MID+20, TOP+5);  // brim of hat
      g.fillRect(MID-15, TOP-20, 30, 25);        // top of hat
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SnowManPanel mainPanel = new SnowManPanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SnowManPanel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Note that top level windows such as JApplets and JFrames are a bit complex and have multiple roles as well as multiple layers. One problem is that your program tries to draw directly in the JApplet's paint method, ignoring that the background of the applet is drawn by another layer, by its contentPane, a JPanel that it holds all of the applet's content. By not calling the super.paint(...) method it also risks corrupting the applet's painting chain -- since the applet's own painting (called via the `super.paint(...)`) is ultimately responsible for painting all of the applet including its borders and its child components.

Comment: Thank for the input, your program does exactly what I described. But even if the code I posted is not the most efficient way, shouldn't it still work? What are the chances that my textbook is wrong? (It's the latest version)

Comment: @Stephanie: top level windows such as JApplets and JFrames are a bit complex and have multiple roles as well as multiple **layers**. One problem is that your program tries to draw directly in the JApplet's paint method, ignoring that the background of the applet is drawn by another layer, by its contentPane, a JPanel that it holds all of the applet's content. By not calling the `super.paint(...)` method it also risks corrupting the applet's painting mechanism..

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I feel that your last comment should be part of your answer, and not a comment.  After all, the question was "why is this not working", not "what should I do instead of this".